# Execute hyperlink automatically

Tags: vba, hyperlink, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

I have VBA code that I'm using in PowerPoint to execute hyperlink automatically, but it doesn't work and I cant seem to find what is happening, here is the code:

```vb
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
    ' This code runs when the slide changes during a slideshow

    ' Check if the current slide is the last slide
    If Wn.View.CurrentShowPosition = Wn.Presentation.Slides.Count Then
        ' Follow the hyperlink to "Loop Presentation" located on the desktop
        Wn.Presentation.FollowHyperlink Address:="C:\Users\YourUsername\Desktop\hyperlilnk test 2.pptx"
    End If
End Sub
```

I wanted this code to execute at the end of presentation to open another presentation through hyper link

Comment: Does it have to be done with a HyperLink? Why not just use                                  `Presentations.Open "C:\Users\YourUsername\Desktop\hyperlilnk test 2.pptx"`

Comment: @DecimalTurn has the correct answer here, but to add a bit more info, IF you have a hyperlink added to a shape on a slide, you can iterate the slide object's .HyperLinks collection and for each hyperlink, call its .Follow method.